# Problems making a simple website-layout with Flex in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I'm new to Bootstrap and web developing and want to design a simple welcome-page which should looks like this:

[image: Website layout]

The colors show where flex rows could be placed. The second row should have the required height. The first row should fill the remaining height.
The middle text should be centered vertically and horicontally and the text on the right bottom should be centered to the right.

I've read the complete documentation about flex in bootstrap 5 but it is very difficult to combine all possibilities.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add `min-vh-100` to the body. This will ensure that the body is at least as high as the viewport.
2. Add Flexbox to the body by adding `d-flex`
3. To have the elements belwo eachotherwithin a Flexbox, you also ahve to add `flex-column` to change the default flex-direction from row to column
4. To consume all remaining height of a flex-item within a flex-container you have to add `flex-grow-1` to that element.
5. to horizontally and vertically center elements, you need to use flexbox aswell with `d-flex`. To maintain the normal Block-Level behavior you should also use `flex-column`. To horizontally center (side-axis in this case) you use `align-items-center` and to vertically center (main-axis in this case) you use `justify-content-center`

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<body class="min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
  <main class="flex-grow-1 bg-danger d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <h1>WELCOME</h1>
    <p>to this test</p>
  </main>
  <footer class="bg-info">footer</footer>
</body>
```

Personally I would highly recommend you not to learn programming websites with Bootstrap or any other library. Learn the normal CSS. If you would be able to achieve that design using flexbox and know how flexbox works with normal CSS, you have it way easier to search for the right Bootstrap classes. You need to learn a fundemental base knowledge and understand how programming works if you want to be an effictive webdeveloper. Bootstrap can make things easier but is not a replacement to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

That layout is extremely simple to achieve using standard CSS.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#page {
  background-color: #ff6666;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 1fr) auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}

main {
  place-self: center; /* horizontal and vertical centering */
}

footer {
  background-color: #6666ff;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <main>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </main>
  <footer>
    &copy; 2021 whatever
  </footer>
</div>
```